# Get value from list in pandas

Tags: python, list, pandas

I have a panda data frame (Python 2.11) containing the time as text in one column (format hh:mm:ss). I want to get the hours (minustes or seconds) only. For that I create a list

```
df.Time.str.split(":")
```

This way I get a list e.g. `[10,23,00]`. How can I access the first (second, or third) value to continue working for each row in the data frame?

```
df.Time.str.split(":")[0]
```

returns the first row but not the first element.

Answer (score 5):

I think you need parameter `expand=True` - then output is 3 columns of `df`:

```
df.Time.str.split(":", expand=True)
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time':['10:23:00', '11:23:00']})

print (df)
       Time
0  10:23:00
1  11:23:00

df[['hour','minute','seconds']] = df.Time.str.split(":", expand=True)
print (df)
       Time hour minute seconds
0  10:23:00   10     23      00
1  11:23:00   11     23      00
```

If dont need all values is possible use `.str[]` for select values of lists - [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#splitting-and-replacing-strings):

```
df['hour'] = df.Time.str.split(":").str[0]
df['minute'] = df.Time.str.split(":").str[1]
print (df)
       Time hour minute
0  10:23:00   10     23
1  11:23:00   11     23
```